# Why is the word "is" skipped?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

I was watching something and someone said this

> Interior, Outer Space. A distopian future. The year is 1000. An astronaut floats in. His eyes are average, his face fine.

"His face fine" sounds like it is skipping the word "is", like something a caveman would say. Is this good English or was this a mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"His face **is** fine" <- that "**is**" is implied in the previous **are**.

Consider the following:

> His eyes are blue, his hair white and his coat long.

When being poetic, you don't need the remaining is/are, no matter how many are followed by the first one, which already implies itself to the rest of the sentence.

Comment: thanks, could you say "His eyes blue, his hair white, and his coat long"?

Comment: I'd say that, on its own, this wouldn't constitute a sentence as it doesn't contain a verb. You could, however write/say: "His eyes blue, his hair white, and his coat long, John made a striking impression."

Comment: There is a verb. The verb is "are".

Comment: @QUrbycoz: I was answering Limb0x0y's comment.

Answer (score 5):

It's a perfectly normal construction, forms of which are found in many languages. It is one form of [Ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29).

Answer (score -1):

It's fine, it's a stylistic choice. Usually there's a pause (and a comma) between "face" and "fine".

Comment: -1: I don't agree that *usually* there's a pause and certainly not a comma. Furthermore, it has nothing to do with what the OP is asking and if he's a beginner, this may only further confuse him.

Comment: I think there *is* an implied pause in OP's example, and in most corresponding usages. In some ways the stylistic choice here is *not* to include it, forcing the reader to reflect more on exactly what the words are intending to convey. After all, you do need to think a bit to figure out what "fine" might mean when used to describe an astronaut's face.